# CloudFormation create EC2 specify subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I 've CloudFormation template. What should I do if I have a few VPC settings and need to install an EC2 instance according to the VPC that I chose? So, How can i set automatically SubnetID in EC2 settings ? (SubnetId) If i set manually it works perfectly. Thanks for helps.

PS: I select minumum 2 subnets for AutoScale structure. So how i can do ?

`SubnetId: 'subnet-020ecb673c3174657'`

My template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  Ant Media Server AutoScaling CloudFormation Templates.
  If you have any questions, please just drop a line to contact (at) antmedia.io
Parameters:
  VpcId:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC::Id'
    Description: VpcId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)
    ConstraintDescription: must be the VPC Id of an existing Virtual Private Cloud.
  Subnets:
    Type: 'List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>'
    Description: The list of SubnetIds in your Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)
    ConstraintDescription: >-
      must be a list of at least two existing subnets associated with at least
      two different availability zones. They should be residing in the selected
      Virtual Private Cloud.
  InstanceType:
    Description: Ant Media Server EC2 instance type
    Type: String
    Default: t2.large
    AllowedValues:
      - t2.large
      - t2.xlarge
      - t2.2xlarge
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid EC2 instance type.

  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instances
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName'
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '255'
    AllowedPattern: '[\x20-\x7E]*'
    ConstraintDescription: can contain only ASCII characters.
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})'
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.

Resources:
  DBEC2SecurityGroup:
      Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
      Properties:
        GroupDescription: SecurityGroup
        SecurityGroupIngress:
          - IpProtocol: tcp
            FromPort: '22'
            ToPort: '22'
            CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  DBInstance:
      Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
      Properties:
        KeyName: !Ref KeyName
        ImageId: 'ami-0287acb18b6d8efff'
        InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
        SubnetId: 'subnet-020ecb673c3174657'
        Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Test
```

Comment: you can reference the subnets property. `SubnetId: !Ref Subnets`. it will use the subnet selected. is that what you want

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i tried and not worked. Because i select minumum 2 subnets for AutoScale structure. So if i select 2 subnets ?

Comment: if you have a autoscaling group resource in your template, you can configure multiple subnets in the `VPCZoneIdentifier` property of the autoscaling group. yes you can have separate parameters to input more subnets.

Comment: I mean, i use this template with autoscale but install seperate EC2 instance. It 's my custom image. I can do another select box for my custom ec2 subnet, but i m try to finding out without extra select box.

Comment: If you have two subnets provide, you should be able to chose the first one for your instance if you want . Ex: `SubnetId: !Select [0, !Ref Subnets]`.

Comment: Thnaks. But it doesnt work with Parameter `  Subnets:
    Type: 'List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>'`